# ConsumeKafkaRecord on nifi cluster optimization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

i'm using a 3 node cluster in nifi with 3 zookeepers.
the general flow is <read from kafka> -> <process data> -> <upload to DB>
should the kafka consume should opereate only on the primary node to prevent group rebalancing every couple of seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, kafka consume processor work well in cluster.
juste make sur to define the same group.id for your connecter.

if you have rebalancing problem you should look at your kafka cluster and nifi stability first.

Comment: yeah. i guess that was the problem. we stopped using the cluster and it solved the roblem.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed the exact same flow with similar cluster, may be the processing piece of it is more complex.

I have 3 node nifi cluster and the consumer is running on all the 3 nodes with the same group id. This helps in distributing the processing cost to all the nodes at the same time it provides a much better performance. In case you are experiencing more rebalancing, it might be a different issue in your data flow.